# Android, SQLITE: Failed to read row 0, column 11 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 11 columns

Tags: android, sql, database, json, sqlite

Failed to read row 0, column 11 from a CursorWindow which has 1 rows, 11 columns.

That's the error I get when I want to read the data from my database(when I'm logging in). It also says "app stopped working".
This is the JSON response:

```
E/JSON﹕ {"tag":"login","success":1,"error":0,"user":{"fname":"somefirstname","lname":"somelastname","email":"some@email.com","uname":"someuser","address":"someaddress","tel":"somephone","dob":"15\/01\/1997","ptc":"somepostco","id":"3","created_at":"2013-12-28 01:20:33"}}
12-27 17:23:14.602
```

Also the next error by the previous one is this "Couldn't read row 0, col 11 from CursorWindow." it's the created_at string, and when I remove that, it logs in without a crash but it reads the data wrong...

This is my DatabaseHandler.java

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "login";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "member";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_FIRSTNAME = "fname";
    private static final String KEY_LASTNAME = "lname";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "uname";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    private static final String KEY_TELEPHONE = "tel";
    private static final String KEY_DATEOFBIRTH = "dob";
    private static final String KEY_POSTCODE = "ptc";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LASTNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_USERNAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_TELEPHONE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_DATEOFBIRTH + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_POSTCODE + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String fname, String lname, String email, String uname, String uid, String address, String tel, String ptc, String dob, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_FIRSTNAME, fname); // FirstName
        values.put(KEY_LASTNAME, lname); // LastName
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_USERNAME, uname); // UserName
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address); // Address
        values.put(KEY_TELEPHONE, tel); // Telephone
        values.put(KEY_DATEOFBIRTH, dob); // Date of Birth
        values.put(KEY_POSTCODE, ptc); // ZIP code
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("id", cursor.getString(1)); // id - uid
            user.put("username", cursor.getString(2)); // uname - username
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("fname", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("lname", cursor.getString(6));
            user.put("dob", cursor.getString(7));
            user.put("tel", cursor.getString(8));
            user.put("address", cursor.getString(9));
            user.put("ptc", cursor.getString(10));
            //user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(11));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }


    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }

}
```

and this is my .sql database

```
CREATE TABLE `login`.`member` (   
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
`encrypted_password` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,    
`email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
`fname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
`lname` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
`dob` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL, 
`tel` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,  
`address` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`ptc` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,  
`salt` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL   
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

This all happened when I updated my database, previously it had only username, fname, lname, id and created_at strings, then I added some other ones and this happened. Remember, before it had read the data correctly in my account info in the app, so you don't say something like my tags/ids are wrong etc...

```
public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("id", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("username", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("fname", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("lname", cursor.getString(5));
            user.put("dob", cursor.getString(6));
            user.put("tel", cursor.getString(7));
            user.put("address", cursor.getString(8));
            user.put("ptc", cursor.getString(9));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(10));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }
```

This is my API for login

```
$response["success"] = 1;
$response["user"]["fname"] = $user["fname"];
$response["user"]["lname"] = $user["lname"];
$response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
$response["user"]["uname"] = $user["username"];
$response["user"]["address"] = $user["address"];
$response["user"]["tel"] = $user["tel"];
$response["user"]["dob"] = $user["dob"];
$response["user"]["ptc"] = $user["ptc"];
$response["user"]["id"] = $user["id"];
$response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a problem that on your Android SQLite `CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE` statement, there is no creation of column `encrypted_password`. Then your table has only 11 columns which leads to maximum index 10. There is no column with index 11 and no column with name `encrypted_password` and calling `cursor.getString(11);` is the reason of error which force closes your application.

**Problem of all your reading of database data are hard coded indexes which do not match order of created columns.** When you create your table on your `onCreateDatabase()` method, column order is:

1. id
2. fname
3. lname
4. email

etc. due to order of column names in create table statement.

Than in your `getUserDetails` method, you are taking fname with index 5, lname with index 6 etc. hard coded indexes does not match the order of columns in create table statement and you take username and id values instead of fname and lname. Simmilar it is for other columns.

For properly work with column indexes, you should use `getColumnIndex(String columnName)` method on `Cursor` instead of hard coded indexes. For example:

```
int fnameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME);
String fname = cursor.getString(fnameIndex);
```

Here is snippet of code you could use in your `getUserDetails()` method:

```
    user.put("id", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ID))); // id - uid
    user.put("username", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME))); // uname - username
    user.put("email", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL)));
    user.put("fname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_FIRSTNAME)));
    user.put("lname", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_LASTNAME)));
    user.put("dob", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATEOFBIRTH)));
    user.put("tel", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_TELEPHONE)));
    user.put("address", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_ADDRESS)));
    user.put("ptc", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(KEY_CREATED_AT)));
```

Comment: I don't fully understand this, could you write me the full code of public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)  ? And also, without address, telephone, date of birth and post code, the account info is printed perfect with no errors, so idk about this theory for encrypted_password cause my API solves that, I added my API in the post btw

Comment: I cannot write you onCreate method which will work because of different indexes in your code. Index is order of column creation in your on create statement so you should sync column order in your CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE statement and cursor.getString() methods. Check edit.

Comment: Well, some fields get work some not. ;) Now the columns are read properly so there are incorrect values in db columns. There may be problem in inserting values. I see a lot of string parameters in row in your addUser method. Maybe their order is swapped on this method call. I will suggest you to get your database from device and check column values visually. You can use SQLite Manager plugin for Firefox. Db file from device can be get simply by getting its file if it is publicly accessible or via sqlite3 tool if it is in your private storage.